# Live traffic data API or Web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, api, google-maps-api-3

I want to develop an application that will show the real time traffic data from different cities of India.
I want to store traffic data into database. I want only traffic data and not Traffic Incidents.

I am looking Free one.

I have Google it and found below API or web-service. But these are not useful for me.

1. MapQuest API - This API is not working for Indian cities and it is not giving traffic data.
2. Yahoo Traffic Web Service APIs - This API is shut down.
3. Bing Map API - It is only giving Traffic Incidents and not the Traffic Data.

Can any one suggest any FREE API or Web Service that will provide me the real time traffic data from different cities present in India.
Please can any one help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I did not try the following services but these are also there :

TomTom traffic web service 
esri World map service

Please try and let me know if it helps you.

Sharad Arya